# How can I transform a date/time coming from an excel file to momentjs utc date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am having some issues transforming an excel time to UTC.

The time I am receiving from excel comes in this shape: `0.3333333333333333` it is a number between `0` and `1`.

I have this code:

```js
  const formatTime = (days) => {
    const timeFormated = new Date(days * 864e5).toLocaleString("en-US", {
      timeStyle: "short",
      timeZone: "UTC",
    });

    return new moment.utc(timeFormated, "HH:mm").format();
  };
```

So let's say I pass this to moment: `formatTime(0.3333333333333333)`

I am getting an string like this instead of only the time:

```
"2020-06-08T20:00:00Z"
```

I need to present the user the time only, like this: `6:00 PM` or whatever the outcome is, it should be in UTC human readable.

Please notice I am doing a thing with `toLocaleString` which I don't know if it is right. So I would like to get some advice if I am doing it wrong or not and how can I achieve to show the user the time only. You know, hours and minutes.

Comment: Have you tried passing a format there like this: `format('h:mm:ss a')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the format string to the momentjs formatter

i.e

```
return new moment.utc(timeFormated, "HH:mm").format("HH:mm A");
```

format `A`  for AM PM

Moment JS docs https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

It looks like your timeFormated has the proper format as @Non said. You could just return timeFormated on your formatTime function unless you want have a slightly different format i.e. 'h:mm:ss a', in that case you can use the format function as show on my example.

Comment: What about the variable `timeFormated`, is that ok?

Comment: @Non just printed timeFormated to console. Its look like you could just return timeFormated